# Not able to add example utterance for an intent through Luis portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Not able to add example utterance for a new or existing intent in Luis portal.

I can create Intent but example utterance section looks all grey. I am following the documentation/sample below
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-quickstart-intents-only

Already tried in different browsers.

Comment: Could you please add screenshot? I see your score is low - so you may include the screenshot as link - and someone else may modify it as inline.

Comment: Could you share the screenshot on how the option looks like for you?

Answer (score 0):

By providing example utterances, you are training LUIS about what kinds of utterances should be predicted for the intent.The below snapshot shows how to add the example utterances.I hope this helps!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this behavior - see screenshot of inability to enter utterances into a defined intent (from the LUIS portal). Here an intent has been drilled-into and no UX for entering utterances is apparent.

[image]